# Matlab - how to analyse sequences of binary behavioural responses?

Tags: matlab, sequence, analysis

I am interested in the effect of previous responses on the current response in a behavioural test. For example if on three previous trials in my test a participant answers *'no', 'yes', 'yes'* the likelihood of a 'yes' response on the current trial is different than if they had previously answered *'yes', 'yes', 'no'*, and so on.

To analyse this I need to find all instances of particular sequences of responses in my dataset. e.g. every time *yes yes yes* occurs, every time *yes yes no* occurs..., and so forth for all possible permutations of yes/no sequences.

To do this I can hard code a long chain of if/else statements in Matlab (to work on a fixed number of previous trials), or I can write each possible sequence out and search for it but both methods are very slow to write.

Rather than code by hand for a fixed number of previous trials, i.e. the previous three responses, is there a sensible solution to use instead for the previous **n** trials?  i.e. as soon as I want to analyse, say, the previous 5 trials, rather than the previous 3, the chain of if/else statements required becomes unbearable!

NB. The response data is always binary (i.e. left vs right, or yes vs no, etc.).

Many thanks in advance.

*EDIT*
The following illustration might help to clarify. This quick example runs through each response in a sequence and, if the current response is a 'y', counts the number of instances of each permutation of yes/no in the previous 2 trials.

```
mySequenceData = {'y' 'y' 'y' 'n' 'n' 'y' 'n' 'n' 'y' 'y' 'n' 'y'};
numPreviousTrials = 2;

yyCount = 0;
ynCount = 0;
nyCount = 0;
nnCount = 0;

for i = numPreviousTrials+1:length(mySequenceData)
    currentTrial = mySequenceData(i);
    if strcmp(mySequenceData(i), 'y')
        if strcmp(mySequenceData(i-1), 'y')
            if strcmp(mySequenceData(i-2), 'y')
                yyCount = yyCount+1;
            elseif strcmp(mySequenceData(i-2), 'n')
                nyCount = nyCount+1; 
            end
        elseif strcmp(mySequenceData(i-1), 'n')
            if strcmp(mySequenceData(i-2), 'y')
                ynCount = ynCount+1;
            elseif strcmp(mySequenceData(i-2), 'n')
                nnCount = nnCount+1; 
            end
        end
    end                       
end
```

If I now want to count the y/n permutations in the previous 3 trials, or 5 trials, and so on, I have to re-write it all, and using if/else statements becomes almost unworkable.

My problem is in trying to find a solution I can write for n trials from the outset, rather than a specific number of previous trials.

Thanks again.

Comment: Post an example with input and desired output, to clarify what you want

Comment: Thanks Luis, I've updated the post with an example.

Comment: you have a binary choice: 'yes' or 'no' so you have better to use 1 or 0.

Comment: @obchardon Thanks. I will be using 1s and 0s, I only used y/n above to try to illustrate the problem (which remains even if coding of data is as 0/1 rather than y/n).

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you:

```
mySequenceData = [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0];

N = length(mySequenceData);
for j = 1:N-1 
n = j;
A1 = [0:2^n-1]'; %'
A2{j} = rem(floor(A1*pow2(-(n-1):0)),2);
for i = n:length(mySequenceData)
short_seq =  mySequenceData(i-n+1:i);   
out{i-n+1} = ismember(A2{j},short_seq,'rows');                     
end
counting      = cellfun(@find,out,repmat({1},1,length(out)));
counting_N{j} = histc(counting,[1:length(A2{j})]);
end
```

The matrix A2 list all the possible binary combination.
The matrix counting_N count the number of time that a combination appears.

Comment: This is great, thank you. It will take me a little while to figure out exactly how it works (I'm still new to this...), but it does it work!